# What's the equivalent for LISTAGG (Oracle database) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation, listagg

I have to replace the Oracle driver with the newest PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL doesn't know the function LISTAGG. I have to `concat` values by comma separated. What's the equivalent for the Oracle's function `LISTAGG` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: A simple google search and I found http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/191-String-Aggregation-in-PostgreSQL,-SQL-Server,-and-MySQL.html on top.

Comment: Why not simply check the chapter ["Aggregate Functions"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) from the manual?

Comment: Just create one: CREATE FUNCTION LISTAGG....

Comment: @FrankHeikens Why to **create** a function? `LISTAGG` is an **in-built function** in Oracle from version 11g and up.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: If you want the same function name in PostgreSQL, you have to create it. This question isn't about a standard function in Oracle, it's about a function in PostgreSQL with a different name. And you could create a function with the same name so you don't have to change your current code.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Oh, OK. You are talking about PostgreSQL. I agree with you, good idea to create a **user defined function**.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The equivalent function in PostgreSQL is `STRING_AGG()`

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG (column_name,', ') 
FROM my_table
```

> [**string_agg**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) : input values concatenated into a string, separated by delimiter

For example, get list of all `agreement_id` then represent it in a string, in Apache Ofbiz 17.12.04

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(agreement_id, ', ') FROM agreement_item;

-- result
-- "8000, DS-1000-SALES, DS-1000-PURCH, 9000, AGR_SALES"
```

Comment: (SELECT c_id, STRING_AGG(c_grp_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c_grp_id) AS group_ids FROM c_grp_at GROUP BY c_id) puts ERROR: function string_agg(bigint, unknown, bigint) does not exist
  Hinweis: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @cy221 `STRING_AGG(c_grp_id::text, ',')`

Comment: The problem was WITHIN GROUP. I removed that.

Answer (score 16):

From Postgres 9.0 or later, I believe you could do something like this:

```
SELECT c_id, STRING_AGG(c_grp_id, ',' ORDER BY c_grp_id) AS group_ids 
FROM c_grp_at 
GROUP BY c_id
```