# Concat results with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, select, concatenation

I am using PostgreSQL.  I have one table with columns: id, city, country.
I have several cities for each country.

For example:

```
ID     Country     City
1      Brazil      Rio de Janeiro
2      Argentina   Buenos Aires
3      Argentina   Bariloche
```

And I want a SELECT that returns something like

```
Country     Cities
Brazil      (Rio de Janeiro)
Argentina   (Buenos Aires, Bariloche)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what have you tried so far?  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557563/whats-the-equivalent-for-listagg-in-postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to get in result set - you can use `array_agg()` or `string_agg()` functions.

```
WITH t(id,country,city) AS ( VALUES
  (1,'Brazil','Rio de Janeiro'),
  (2,'Argentina','Buenos Aires'),
  (3,'Argentina','Bariloche')
)
SELECT country,'(' || string_agg(city,',') || ')' FROM t
GROUP BY country;
```