# ORACLE "connect by" to POSTGRESQL conversion

Tags: postgresql

How to convert/re-write the below SQL to PostgreSQL? I'm not sure how to convert the `connect by level` and `listagg` in postgreSQL.

```
select listagg(dt,'  ') within group (order by lvl), NBR
from 
(
select level lvl,
case when level=1 then TO_CHAR(a.dt2,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
else
TO_CHAR(a.dt2+(1/1440*30*(level-1)),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
end
dt,10 NBR from 
(select to_date('08/11/2021 18:30:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt1,to_date('08/11/2021 01:30:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt2 from dual) a
start with level=0
connect by level<=1+(to_date('08/11/2021 18:30:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-to_date('08/11/2021 13:30:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))*24*2)
GROUP BY NBR;
```

Output:

```
08/11/2021 01:30:00
08/11/2021 02:00:00
08/11/2021 02:30:00
08/11/2021 03:00:00
08/11/2021 03:30:00
08/11/2021 04:00:00
08/11/2021 04:30:00
08/11/2021 05:00:00
08/11/2021 05:30:00
08/11/2021 06:00:00
08/11/2021 06:30:00
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you face when converting this, where are you stuck? What doesn't work as expected when you try to run it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert the connect by level and listagg in postgreSQL

Comment: See [What's the equivalent for LISTAGG (Oracle database) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29557563/1048572) for the second question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the `group by nbr` is supposed to achieve - as far as I can tell this serves no purpose.

The convoluted `connect by level` in Oracle can be replaced with a simple `generate_series()` in Postgres.

So the following will generate 11 timestamp values from `2021-08-11 01:30:00` to `2021-08-11 06:30:00`:

```
select g.dt
from generate_series(timestamp '2021-08-11 01:30:00', 
                     timestamp '2021-08-11 06:30:00', 
                     interval '30 minute') as g(dt)
```

This can then be aggregated back into a string using `string_agg()`

```
select string_agg(to_char(dt, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), ' '), 10 as nbr
from generate_series(timestamp '2021-08-11 01:30:00', 
                     timestamp '2021-08-11 06:30:00', 
                     interval '30 minute') as g(dt)
```

If you need the number of rows generated, you can use the `with ordinality` clause to get that:

```
select string_agg(to_char(dt, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), ' '), max(idx) as nbr
from generate_series(timestamp '2021-08-11 01:30:00', 
                     timestamp '2021-08-11 06:30:00', 
                     interval '30 minute') with ordinality as g(dt,idx)
```

Comment: Hi - Thank you. I think made a confusion while pasting the o/p. Here 10(nbr) is not constant. It is the count of no of timestamp generated. I.e. here nbr should be 11.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Shouldn't `count(*)` be easier than `max(idx)`?

Comment: @Bergi: probably makes no difference