# postgresql inner join to string join together

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below query

```
SELECT 
CCTP.C5NCCT AS "Numéro",
CCTSPEP.CBCSPE AS "Spécialité"
FROM FIC.CCTP CCTP
LEFT JOIN FIC.CCTSPEP CCTSPEP ON CCTSPEP.CBNCCT = CCTP.C5NCCT;
```

which returns this result

| Numéro | Spécialité |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 |
| 1 | 24 |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 02 |
| 2 | 06 |
| 3 | 11 |

I want to update the query to get a result similar to this

| Numéro | Spécialité |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01, 24, 25 |
| 2 | 02, 06 |
| 3 | 11 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the equivalent for LISTAGG (Oracle database) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557563/whats-the-equivalent-for-listagg-oracle-database-in-postgresql)

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  distinct CCTP.C5NCCT AS Numéro, 
  (
    SELECT 
      STUFF(
        (
          SELECT 
            ',' + etm.Spécialité AS Spécialité 
          FROM 
            (
              select 
                distinct CCTP.C5NCCT, 
                cast(
                  CCTP.CBCSPE as nvarchar(100)
                ) as Spécialitéfrom FIC.CCTP 
                LEFT JOIN FIC.CCTSPEP CCTSPEP ON CCTSPEP.CBNCCT = CCTP.C5NCCT
            ) etm 
          WHERE 
            etm.C5NCCT = FIC.CCTP.C5NCCT 
          ORDER BY 
            etm.C5NCCT FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 
        1, 
        1, 
        ''
      ) AS expr
  ) Spécialité
```

Comment: i have this error: `SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0104] Elément syntaxique é n'est pas correct. Eléments possibles : , FROM INTO.`

Comment: chake this Replase name table name with  
select distinct table1.C5NCCT AS Numéro, ( SELECT STUFF(
          (SELECT ',' + etm.Spécialité AS Spécialité FROM (
              select distinct table1.C5NCCT , cast(table1.CBCSPE as nvarchar(100)) as Spécialité
               from FIC.table1 LEFT JOIN FIC.table2 CCTSPEP ON table2.CBNCCT = table1.C5NCCT

                                  ) etm WHERE  etm.C5NCCT =FIC.table1.C5NCCT 
                ORDER BY etm.C5NCCT FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  AS expr ) Spécialité 
    from table1