Concatenate columns from another table into single column of new table
I wish to concatenate all the results from TableB into a column in TableA, something like this.
UPDATE tableA SET column=CONCAT( 
    SELECT col FROM tableB WHERE tableA.key = tableB.keyA
    )


So if table B is like this



keyA
col




1
A


1
B


1
C



After the operation, key 1 of tableA would look like this



key
column




1
A B C



This is a "one time" operation to migrate some data and then delete the second table

Create a view instead. Redundancy leads to inconsistency.

After the operation has been performed< I intend to delete the second table

I see. But I'd still prefer the original design.

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557563/whats-the-equivalent-for-listagg-oracle-database-in-postgresql
